# Remove specific categories from Seaborn Boxplot

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I have this code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
sns.boxplot(data=resolved_time_length,
x='Time_to_resolve_days',y='Ticket_category',
       linewidth=2.5)#, hue='Priority_level')#,color='pink')

plt.xlim(-1,30)

plt.title('Average Time to Resolve an IoT Ticket in Days',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Resolve Time in Days',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Ticket Category', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

and it produces this graph:

[image]

All I wan t to do is to not show any category in the Y axis that has less than 5 observations(in this case they are the Functionality, Internal-Add and Internal-Data Categories).
I have tried by setting the y axis to be:

```
y=Time_to_resolve_days['Ticket_category']<5
```

but this does not work so I need your help please!

Comment: First filter the dataframe by the condition. Only once that's done, plot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Tested, the following works:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))


#create a filtered dataframe
data=resolved_time_length.drop(columns=resolved_time_length.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=0).index[resolved_time_length.apply(pd.Series.nunique, axis=0)<5])


#plot filtered dataframe
sns.boxplot(data=data,
x='Time_to_resolve_days',y='Ticket_category',
       linewidth=2.5)#, hue='Priority_level')#,color='pink')


plt.xlim(-1,30)

plt.title('Average Time to Resolve an IoT Ticket in Days',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Resolve Time in Days',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Ticket Category', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Comment: your second option produces a `ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Time_to_resolve_days'` error

Comment: @RaulGonzales does the first work? and could you share a sample dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter Pandas DataFrame using **pandas.DataFrame.loc¶**:

```
resolved_time_length.loc[resolved_time_length['Time_to_resolve_days'] < 5]
```

Then, use the filtered DataFrame as the input data:

```
sns.boxplot(data=resolved_time_length.loc[resolved_time_length['Time_to_resolve_days'] < 5], 
x='Time_to_resolve_days',
y='Ticket_category', linewidth=2.5)#, 
hue='Priority_level')#,color='pink')
```

More information here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: that just throws up an error mate but thanks for trying

Comment: that extra bracket is not needed mate. The result is still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

With Seaborn, you can set a `order`-attribute in the `boxplot()`-method. Only the values, witch are in this order will be displayed.

Therfore your code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))
sns.boxplot(
  data=resolved_time_length,
  x='Time_to_resolve_days',
  y='Ticket_category',
  order=['Platform', 'Billing'],
  linewidth=2.5,
  hue='Priority_level',
  color='pink')

plt.xlim(-1,30)

plt.title('Average Time to Resolve an IoT Ticket in Days',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Resolve Time in Days',fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Ticket Category', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

In the above example, only the categories 'Platform' and 'Billing' will be shown in the chart.

For more information see: https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/35-control-order-of-boxplot